# How to make CSS outline cornered?

Tags: css, outline

I have code that provides me that

[image]

CSS Code:

```
  .about-best-big-vector-right {
  width: 1380px;
  float: right;
  border-top: 140px solid #272838;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  outline: 3px solid #eda225;
  outline-offset: .3rem;
  -moz-outline-radius-bottomleft: 2em;
}
```

HTML Code:  `<div class="about-best-big-vector-right"></div>`

But I want to achive that and can't make cornered bottom-left?
[image]

Comment: Please show the complete relevant code.

Comment: @AhmadHabib Code that I wrote is my code and don't know what should I show more?

Comment: At least the HTML & CSS part that is relevant to the image.

Comment: @AhmadHabib I added the relevant html code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use border for this, use skew transformation:

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-right: -10px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000 content-box;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```